# Check if all values in first td in each tr are contain the same text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem where I have a dynamically created table (3x3, 4x4, or 5x5) I am trying to see if the text in each column is equal starting with the first.

I have tried this so far

```
$('tr td:first-child').find('td:contains(X)');

<table id="grid">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>X</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>X</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Above is an example of a table created that has two X's in the first column
To try and get the first child in every tr but I think that is wrong. I need to compare the values and if they all are equal I need to stop the search.

Comment: share your tried code ..?

Comment: I did?
    $('tr td:first-child').find('td:contains(X)')
How ever this is not returning properly

Comment: Should the text be equal for each row in each column, or only the first row?

Comment: It would help if you share your html lines for the table. And in the best case a small little working example

Comment: I need to check each row, but if one row happens to be equal first I need stop checking.

Comment: You need to add a little more detail in your question: when you compare the text in each column against the first column, do you want to do it on each row, or only on the first row? What if the condition is true for all but one rows? Is it an `ALL` or `OR` thing that you are looking for?

Comment: I want it to do each row. So say index 0 in each row, compare to see if they say all equal X. And then do this for each index in a row if the first does not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and comments, I believe your requirements are as follow:

- Iterate through all rows in the table
- For each row, compare all subsequent columns with the *first* column

  - If it is the same, move on to the next row
  - If it is *not* the same, stop

With that in mind, your logic is going to be quite straight forward:

1. Iterate through all `<tr>` elements
2. In each row, get the first column text and the array of text content in all subsequent columns. This can be done using `jQuery.map(...).get()`
3. Iterate through this array and compare each element to the first column text

   - If is equivalent, we move on to the next row (by returning `true`)
   - If is different, we stop where we are (by returning `false`)

Here is the logic, written out in JS:

```
// Iterate through each table row
$('tr').each(function() {
  // Get text content if first column
  var firstColumnText = $('td', this).first().text();

  // Construct array of text from all remaining <td>s
  var otherColumnText = $('td', this).not(':first').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();

  // Iterate through array and check if something is different
  // Assume text is the same
  var isEquivalent = true;
  $.each(otherColumnText, function(idx, thisColumnText) {
    if (thisColumnText !== firstColumnText) {
      isEquivalent = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // Stop loop when we encounter the first non-equivalent row
  return isEquivalent;
});
```

Check the proof-of-concept below: identical rows are highlighted in green, rows with one or more different columns compared to the first column is highlighted in red. Note that once the script hits the first non-identical row, it quits iterating (remaining rows are transparent and are no longer checked):

```js
$(function() {
  // Iterate through each table
  $('table').each(function() {

    var currentRowIndex = 0;

    // Iterate through each table row
    $('tr').each(function(i) {

      // Get text content if first column
      var firstColumnText = $('td', this).first().text();
      
      // Construct array of text from all remaining <td>s
      var otherColumnText = $('td', this).not(':first').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
      }).get();
      
      // Iterate through array and check if something is different
      // Assume text is the same
      var isEquivalent = true;
      $.each(otherColumnText, function(idx, thisColumnText) {
        if (thisColumnText !== firstColumnText) {
          isEquivalent = false;
          return false;
        }
      });
      
      // Checking only :)
      if (isEquivalent)
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
      else
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

      // Update row cursor so we know where we stopped
      currentRowIndex = i;
      console.log('Currently looking at row ' + i + '\tIs this row equivalent? ' + isEquivalent);
      
      // Stop loop when we encounter the first non-equivalent row
      return isEquivalent;
    });
    
    // Log the zero-based index of the row where you stopped
    console.log('Last valid row: ' + (currentRowIndex - 1));
    console.log('Stopped at row: ' + currentRowIndex);
  });
});
```

```css
table, table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Different</td>
    <td>Same</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Different</td>
    <td>Same</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
    <td>Same</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```js
var tableElem = $('table');
var rowElems = tableElem.find('tr');

function check() {
  var isEqual = true;

  $.each(rowElems, function(index) {
    $.each($(this).find('td input'), function(index) {
      if(index === 0) {
        col1Val = $(this).val();
      } else {
        if(col1Val !== $(this).val()) {
          isEqual = false;
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });

  if(isEqual) {
    $('#result').text('Is equal');
  } else {
    $('#result').text('Is not equal');
  }
}

$('#check').on('click', function() {
  check();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="A" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <button id="check">Check</button>
```

Just an example of how it could work.